# Parsing date-time input string with omitted minutes, using java.time classes

Tags: parsing, datetime, format, java-time

I have input strings in nearly standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), but the minute-of-hour part is omitted (don't ask why, funky data feed out of my control).

> 2018-01-23T12

How do I parse that while letting the minute-of-hour default to zero?

> 2018-01-23T12:00

## `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`

The default parser for [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) is [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME). This formatter tolerates optional second-of-minute. The fractional second and the second-of-minute are both set to zero.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2018-01-23T12:00" ) ;  // Works.
```

But omitting the minute-of-hour fails, with exception thrown.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2018-01-23T12" ) ;  // Fails.
```

## `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`

I am aware of the [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) class and its ability to tolerate optional parts while setting default values.

But I have been able to use it properly. I tried the pattern `"uuuu-MM-dd HH"` while setting both minute-of-hour and second-of-minute to default to zero.

```
String input = "2018-01-23T12";

DateTimeFormatterBuilder b = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().parseDefaulting( ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR , 0 ).parseDefaulting( ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE , 0 ).appendPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd HH" );
DateTimeFormatter f = b.toFormatter( Locale.US );
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f );
System.out.println( ldt );
```

Exception thrown:

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2018-01-23T12' could not be parsed at index 10
>
> at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1988)
>
> at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1890)
>
> at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
>
> at com.basilbourque.example.App.doIt(App.java:31)
>
> at com.basilbourque.example.App.main(App.java:22)

Comment: It's a bit hacky, but have you thought of `+":00"` to the end of the strings?

Comment: @Autumnal Yes, but… I'm really trying to learn more about how `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` works. In other words, I'm more interested in an education than a solution. This particular problem seemed like a good example for a *Stack Overflow* Question, as none of the other six Questions on `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` with ["optional"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+DateTimeFormatterBuilder+optional) or ["default"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+DateTimeFormatterBuilder+default) cover this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look carefully at the error message, you will see that it says: `Text '2018-01-23T12' could not be parsed at index 10`
This means that the problem is the T in the format.

If we then go back to the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`, the pattern specified is: `"uuuu-MM-dd HH"`. Here is the problem, this specifies a space when there is in fact a T. The solution is to replace this pattern with: `"uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH"`

```
String input = "2018-01-23T12";

DateTimeFormatterBuilder b = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().parseDefaulting( ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR , 0 ).parseDefaulting( ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE , 0 ).appendPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH" );
DateTimeFormatter f = b.toFormatter( Locale.US );
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f );
System.out.println( ldt );
```

> 2018-01-23T12:00

Indeed, you do not even need the builder at all. Specify a `DateTimeFormatter` with that same pattern. The minute-of-hour does default to zero.

```
String input = "2018-01-23T12";

DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

> 2018-01-23T12:00

Comment: Oh, whoops. In my experimenting, I messed that up. Thanks.